# Como remover linhas específicas de um data frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso gerar uma nova tabela apenas com as rodadas horárias.

Por exemplo, desta tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobrariam estes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor forma de resolver este problema no R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas que eu vejo, é verificar se o minuto é igual a 0, logo, seria uma hora exata.

Você pode usar o pacote lubridate para fazer isso de forma mais fácil.

```
##install.packages("lubridate") #É necessário instalar o pacote se você ainda não o tem instalado.

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr) #Vou usar o dplyr para filtar os dados pois também acho mais fáicl, porém, não é estritamente necessário.

## Criando dados fakes
data <- c("01/01/2010 00:50", "01/01/2010 01:00", "01/01/2010 01:20", "01/01/2010 02:00")
chuva <- c(0,0.2,0,0.4)

## Criando o df, e utilizando o lubridate dmy_hm, para identificar e converter os dados das datas para o formato POSIXct
df <- data.frame(data = dmy_hm(data), chuva = as.numeric(chuva))

##Filtrando os dados onde os minutos são igual a zero
dplyr::filter(df, minute(data) == 0)
```

Comment: agradeço a sugestão. Excelente. 

Também encontrei uma outra possibilidade, que compartilho:

`#selecionando apenas horários terminados em 00

df1<- df[grep(":00",df$data),]`